# Unable to upload image from RN app to meteor backend

Tags: meteor, react-native

I want to upload image from my RN app to meteor backend. I am using "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.7" for getting imagefile from gallery or camera and uploading to meteor using package react-native-meteor to collectionFs this is my code of RN app where I am calling meteor method for image upload as soon as user select image:

```js
_handleSelectFile() {
    const { order } = this.state;
    var options = {
        title: 'Select Avatar',
        storageOptions: {
            skipBackup: true,
            path: 'images'
        }
    };
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
        if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log('User cancelled image picker');
        }
        else if (response.error) {
            console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        }
        else {
            // let source = { uri: response.uri };

            // You can also display the image using data:
            let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };
            this.setState({
                order: {
                    ...order,
                    fileName: response.fileName
                }
            });
            let fileData = response.data;
            // const body = new FormData();
            // body.append('file',fileData);
            var photo = {
                url: fileData,
                type: 'image/jpeg',
                name: 'photo.jpg',
            };
            Meteor.FSCollection('orderImages').insert(photo, function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('error during uploading');
                } else {
                    console.log('uploading successfully');
                    // _this.props.navigator.pop();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and this is my server side code:

```js
export const Orders = new Mongo.Collection('orders');
export const OrderImages = new FS.Collection("orderImages", {
    filter: {
        maxSize: 1048576,
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*'],
        }
    },
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("orderImages")]
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {    
    OrderImages.allow({
        insert: function () {
            return true;
        }
    });    
}
```

and I am getting error like this:
ExceptionsManager.js:65

> Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined